# How to load a fragment from another fragment

Tags: dynamic, android-fragments

my fragment contains a list view. I'm using Array adapter for list view. I want to load new fragment when I'm click in the list item. here is my code . TimeLIneFragment is a new one
what will be the parameter in newInstance ?
any answer will be appreciable

```
TimeLineFragment tFragment = TimeLineFragment.newInstance();
            FragmentTransaction ft = tFragment.getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, tFragment);
            ft.commit();
```